# Shortening a string in a where LIKE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server

I am getting a lot of variations in the results of a couple of strings. Specifically, in the LIKE '%Bomgar%' clause. It returns something far longer.

```
select distinct DisplayName0
from v_Add_Remove_Programs
where 
(DisplayName0 like '%Acrobat%' or
DisplayName0 like '%Faxcom%' or
DisplayName0 like 'Bomgar%' or
DisplayName0 like 'Microsoft Office Access%') and
(DisplayName0 not like 'update%' and
DisplayName0 not like 'security%' and
ASCII(left(DisplayName0, 1)) between ASCII('A') and ASCII('Z'))
order by DisplayName0
```

Currently, the results from the %Bomgar% is "Bomgar Representative Console v1.5.1 [XV76J].

Id like to trim it down to just "Bomgar"

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what you want at all.  Please provide some sample input and desired output.  Note that in a like clause that % says that basically anything beyond that marker doesn't matter so something like like 'Bomgar%' will always match something like 'BomgarHEYTHISISEXTRA'

Comment: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: If you just like `'Bomgar'` then use an equal comparison, e.g. `OR DisplayName0 = 'Bomgar'`.

Comment: Right now, the output is: "Bomgar Representative Console v1.5.1 [XV76J]. I just need the output to be "Bomgar"

Comment: [edit] clarifications directly into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manipulate the value directly:

```
select distinct
  case
    when DisplayName0 like '%Bomgar%' then 'Bomgar'
   (similar whens for other search types)
  end as DisplayName0
from ...
where ...
```

Comment: Thank you, Bohemian